# Programa bajo la licencia ISC (Similar a MIT) ¿Qué hacer? ¿Requisitos?

Tags: licencias

He estado leyendo las licencias de código abierto, me interesa mucho la [ISC](https://opensource.org/licenses/ISC). Que a diferencia de la GPL, **no** menciona que tengo que [compartir mi código de fuente](https://choosealicense.com/appendix/#patent-use) (pero igual las personas pueden modificar el programa, no tengo problemas entonces con eso). Mis dudas son:

- Mi programa estará ya como "binario" ¿**En realidad NO es necesario que tenga que compartir mi código de fuente?**, es decir, subirlo a Github o alguna web parecida.
- ¿Las personas pueden pedir el código de fuente y yo tengo que darselo a esa persona?.
- ¿El código de fuente puede compartirse offline?
- ¿Sigue siento open source aunque no comparta mi código de fuente?

---

*Pregunto aquí puesto que sé que ustedes trabajan con licencias y he visto preguntas sobre licencias en stackoverflow en inglés.*

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia entre la ISC y la MIT radica en lo que quieres distribuir.

Si vas a distribuir el programa compilado, listo para usar, **sin cobrar** por la entrega o por el uso, pero manteniendo el copyright, usa la ISC. Tu software es libre o más bien **gratis**... ***free** as a beer*.

Si vas a distribuir el código fuente, documentación, *assets*, etc., como un repositorio de Github, **sin cobro** y permitiendo que lo modifique, lo usen en otros software derivado, etc., pero manteniendo el copyright, usa la MIT. Tu software es libre... ***free** as a bird*.

Comment: Interesante, en la respuesta anterior me mencionaron que practicamente había que distribuir el código de fuente con esa licencia. Utilizaré ISC, entonces, si no lo subo a un repositorio, es valido? y si lo subo también es valido? Por mi programa no cobraré, solo ganare centavos por medio de publicidad, pero es gratuito.

Comment: @Tamara la licencia es para el que recibe no para el que otorga. Pero si no cumples con la definición de software libre, tu programa solo es gratis, pero no _open source_.

Answer (score 1):

> - ¿Las personas pueden pedir el código de fuente y yo tengo que darselo a esa persona?
> - ¿Sigue siento open source aunque no comparta mi código de fuente?

Toda licencia open source te obliga a entregar el fuente. Cuando hablamos de open source estamos hablando también de una ideologoía, además de la parte técnica. Eso incluso podemos verlo en [el sitio oficial de Open Source](https://opensource.org):

> No. The Open Source Definition specifies that Open Source licenses **may not discriminate against persons or groups**. Giving everyone freedom means giving evil people freedom, too.

El open source, como ideología, nos dice como fundamento, que **el fuente debe ser entregado para libre modificación de él por parte del cliente**; lo cual no implica que el cliente pueda hacer cambios sin notificarte y distribuir el programa modificado.

---

#### MIT

La licencia MIT es una licencia **permisiva**. Una licencia permisiva quiere decir que básicamente el cliente puede hacer lo que se le dé la gana con tu fuente, pero siempre deberán darte la atribución correspondiente. Un aspecto importante en esta licencia es que puede ser sublicenciada bajo las modificaciones que un tercero haga:

> including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, **sublicense**, and/or sell copies of the Software.

Para más información ver [esta pregunta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177768/how-do-i-correctly-sub-license-a-library-that-is-under-the-mit-license).

Esta licencia es la más popular en FOSS.

#### ISC

La licencia ISC es igualmente permisiva, es prácticamente igual, funcionalmente, a la licencia MIT y a la BSD-2. Para ser honesto, no veo diferencias en éstas, salvo por las que se dice en [choosealicense](https://choosealicense.com).

#### LGPL

Esta licencia es más restrictiva, por ejemplo, no permite cambios:

> Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies of this license document, **but changing it is not allowed**.

Al ver esta licencia puedes darte cuenta de que *entregar el fuente no quiere decir que se podrá modificar* para ser distribuído bajo estas modificaciones.

---

Las licencias estrictas como la GPL te obligan a abrir tu fuente si usas código licenciado bajo ésta licencia. Por ejemplo, si estás desarrollando una aplicación Java y quieres incluir el controlador de MySQL (GPL 3.0) te verás obligado a abrir el fuente aún si esta no es tu idea. Las licencias más permisivas no te obligan a ésto.

Comment: donde hablas de la MIT yo lo entendi, pero quizas esta parte -> *incluído ser pasar a ser cerrado* puedas modificarla para que sea mas claro, pero solo es una sugerencia, quizas se te colo un "ser" de mas. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel gracias por la correción. He ordenado un poco más la idea con la licencia MIT.

Answer (score 0):

Cualquier licencia de **código abierto** es por definición de **código abierto**.

Aunque **algunas no necesariamente implican entregar el código** con el software (binarios), **debe haber un medio bien publicitado de obtener el código fuente por no más que un costo de reproducción razonable,** preferiblemente descargado desde Internet sin costo.

[Definición de open source](https://opensource.org/osd)

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu última pregunta: **si no compartes el código fuente, no es open source**.

*La licencia aplica al código, no solo al software.* Si no tienes problemas con que la gente modifique el programa, entonces lo más sencillo es que lo distribuyas tanto en forma binaria como el código fuente y cada cual decida.

Si usas una licencia *copyleft* como la ISC *no* estás obligada a entregar el código fuente aunque te lo pidan, pero de nuevo si no tienes problemas con que la gente lo modifique lo mejor es que lo publiques directamente.